# How to Nest Redux Reducers in Arrays?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I can't figure out how to combine reducers in nested arrays. I want to be able to add multiple routines to a list of routines, and i want to be able to add multiple days into each routine.

I cannot figure out how I should be combining these reducers so that I can add days into a list of days in a routine in a list of routines.

Here is a sample state:

```
const sampleState = {
  "routines": [
    {
      "name": "Starting Strengh",
      "days": [
        {
          "dayName": "Chest",
          "exercises": [
            {
              "exerciseName": "Bench Press",
              "sets": 5,
              "reps": 5
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

My routineReducer and routineDayRecuder look like this:

```
function dayReducer(state=[], action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_ROUTINE_DAY:
      return [
        ...state,
        {
          name: action.name,
        }
      ]
    default:
      return state
  }
}

function routineReducer(state=[], action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_ROUTINE:
      return [
        ...state,
        {
          name: action.name,
          days: dayReducer
        }
      ]
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

I'm combining my reducer's like this:

```
const fntnessApp = combineReducers({
  routines: routineReducer,
  routing
})
```

Please help, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reducer is not the state itself it is the function that takes in the type and payload of an action and builds a portion of the state. In this case I would probably make the `routineReducer` and the `routineDayReducer` objects at the root and not lists and the keys within that object would be an id for the routine.

The `dayReducer` would look something like:

```
function dayReducer(state=[], action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_ROUTINE_DAY:
      return {
        ...state,
        [action.routineId] : [
           ...state[action.routineId],
           {
              name: action.name
           }
        ]
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Then when you `mapStateToProps` you can select the days you want for the routine you're looking at by passing a routineId into a selector. Does that make sense? If you want to be able to edit these days as well then you will want to normalize your table like you would in a database and store everything by it's own unique id.

Comment: That makes sense. Basically I want to treat my state as a database, with unique keys so that, when state changes i can select those keys. Thanks!